# LINQ Query Model item passed into the VIewDataDictionary is of type'Microsoft.EntityCoreFramework.Query.Internal.EntityQuerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Logic: Within another razor view when a user clicks on a highlighted row (selects blog), then that particular blogID (bp parameter) is passed to the IActionResult Display to view that blog. I've checked this with a breakpoint and the value is getting passed correctly. In LINQ I want to query using this blogID to bring back results for that particular blogID, and then display that to view.

I'm currently getting the below expection, I believe the model I'm passing to the return View is not type of type BlogViewModel, maybe the LINQ is not return correctly, why is this?

**"The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type** **'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[ViewModels.BlogViewModel]`**

Also should I use a submodel such as Comments or is this a bad idea. I've uploaded the ERD diagram, showing the three tables I'm trying to join in LINQ query.
[image: ERD Diagram]

```
public class CommentModel
{
    [Key]
    public int commentID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Comment")]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Comment is too short")]
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public string reply { get; set; }
    public int blogID { get; set; }
    public string userID { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class BlogViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int blogID { get; set; }

    public string blogTitle { get; set; }
    public string blogContent { get; set; }
    public string userID { get; set; }

    public DateTime publishedDate { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    //Wrap CommentViewModel in this model, so we can use two models in razor view
    public CommentModel Comments { get; set; }
}
```

```
public IActionResult Display(int bp)
{
    var blogResult = from a in _db.Users
                     join b in _db.blog on a.Id equals b.userID where b.blogID == bp
                     join c in _db.comment on b.blogID equals c.blogID
                     select new BlogViewModel {
                         blogID = b.blogID,
                         blogTitle = b.blogTitle,
                         blogContent = b.blogContent,
                         userID = a.Id, 
                         publishedDate = b.publishedDate,
                         firstName = a.firstName,
                         lastName = a.lastName,
                         Comments = new CommentModel { comment = c.comment, commentID = c.commentID, reply = c.reply, blogID = b.blogID, userID = a.Id }
                     };

    return View(blogResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `IQueryable<BlogViewModel>` to the view you should pass instantiated `IEnumerable<BlogViewModel>`:

```cs
return View(blogResult.ToList());
```

I suppose in your view the model should be declared as:

```
@model IEnumerable<BlogViewModel>
```